# Emit local variable which is not a standard type and assign a value to it

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

We can assign a variable using EMIT which has a standard type such as string, etc.
But how can I assign a non-standard type such as Type?

```cs
        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod
            = new DynamicMethod("test",null,null);
        var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        Type types = typeof(StringBuilder);
        LocalBuilder ilType= il.DeclareLocal(typeof(Type));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc,types);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc,ilType);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc,ilType);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call,typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",new[]{typeof(object)})!);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action)).DynamicInvoke();
```

the error output:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
   at test()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

And I want to find a function which I can compile and decompile it to find its IL.
But I cannot find such a function.
Can you solve this question using this method?

Comment: Use LinqPad and decompile `var x = typeof(StringBuilder);` to see how to get type into a variable. (Note that your code seem to be missing at least `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)` and does something strange with value of `types` - it may be good idea to show working version you have for string variable...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I edit the post and add Opcodes.Ret.  But I wonder how can I add non-standard local variable (If I use string , it can work with `ldstd`). But I cannot find example on the Internet to add non-standard type such as `type` or other.

Comment: Strings, Tokens and a few other primitive types can be inserted directly into the IL stream because they have an IL representation. Values/Instances of all other types have to be transported or created by other means like method arguments, fields, constructor calls... To quickly debug IL you can use https://sharplab.io, select "IL" in the "Results" dropdown. To compile and decompile IL use the `ilasm` and `ildasm` command line tools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ilasm-exe-il-assembler